# Como associa uma função de calculo dentro de um função express para usar em routes?

Tags: node.js, express.js, mongoose

To com uma dúvida bem grande, eu tenho uma função que faz cálculos de métricas de usuários e quero colocar ela em uma função express para poder retornar um JSON e usar ela em uma rota, Segue o código para usar nas rotas:

```js
const calculate_followers_week = (req, res) => {
  let user_id = req.params.id;
  UserHistorySchema.find(user_id ? {
      _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user_id)
    } : {}, {
      'history.created_at': 1,
      'history.meta.indicators': 1
    })
    .lean()
    .exec()
    .then(data => {
      res.status(200).json(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).json(err);
    })
}
```

Quero colocar uma função de cálculo dentro dela para ter um retorno JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta alterar o `data` aqui:

```
.then(data => {
    res.status(200).json(data);
})
```

O resultado final podia ser also assim:

```
.then(data => {
    var processado = minhaFuncao(data);
    res.status(200).json(processado);
})
```